# Ncurses/C/C++: Using getstr() and preventing overflow (There must be a better way to do this)

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, buffer-overflow

I am currently jumping into my first full C++ project and I've run into a hitch with Ncurses.

getstr() requires a char array as input, but with this, there is no way to prevent buffer overflow. Lets pretend I'm using this input to get a name. My code would then be the following:

```
int main(){
    char* nameTemp = new char[160];
    initscr();
    getstr(nameTemp);
    endwin();
    delete nameTemp;
    return 0;
}
```

But what  happens if the user decides to use more than 160 characters for his name? I get an error and the program fails. 
Is there a way to fix this kind of fatal flaw in the program besides creating huge Char arrays?
Thanks.

Note: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with g++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
int getnstr(char *str, int n);
```

which reads at most `n` characters.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I knew this existed, but couldn't remember the name when I wrote my answer, and it surprisingly didn't seem to show up when I googled `ncurses getstr()`...

Comment: Thank you! This  is so much better (no offense Jon)

Comment: Haha none taken. I would suggest this over any other hand-written attempt at limiting the number of characters to get from input.

Comment: Rici or @jonhopkins I've posted a new question related to this. Can either of you see if you might be able to help me?

Answer (score 5):

From http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/scanw.html

> 7.3. getstr() class of functions
>   ... In essence, this function performs the same task as would be achieved
>   by a series of calls to getch() until a newline, carriage return, or
>   end-of-file is received. ...

So, while it's not a perfect solution, you could just use `getch()` in a loop until you reach the end of the char array or until the user types a newline.

```
char* nameTemp = new char[160];
int i = 0;
// don't put anything in the last index, to ensure a properly ended string
while (i < 159) {
    nameTemp[i] = getch();
    if (nameTemp[i] == '\n') {
        break;
    } else if (nameTemp[i] == '\b') {
        nameTemp[i] = 0;
        i--;
        nameTemp[i] = 0;
        i--; // cancel out the increment at end of loop
    }
    i++;
}
nameTemp[i] = 0; // the \n or tempName[159], whichever comes first
```

Comment: @lijrobert, I updated the code to explicitly set the last index in `nameTemp` to 0 if the user types too many characters, just in case there is a junk value in that spot when the array is initialized (can't remember if C or C++ zeros arrays when they're initialized)

Comment: I have a new issue now. How would I handle a backspace? I think I know how but its not working...

Comment: Updated with what I *think* will work for backspaces

Answer (score 1):

How about using [getch](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) to get one character at a time?  This way you have full control over what you are reading:

```
    std::string get_line()
    {
      std::string result;
      while(true)
      {
        int c = getch();
        if(c == ERR || c == '\n') return result;
        else result += c; 
      }
    }
```

For example.  (This code is untested).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you could dynamically-allocate a 50MB buffer.  That will ensure that it is not realistically possible to overflow the buffer before the next Patch Tuesday, whereupon your box will get restarted anyway :)

Comment: I don't understand how this helps as I'm using Ubuntu, as stated, and I wanted to avoid allocating huge amounts of memory.

Comment: well you could allocate 50MB buffer even on Ubuntu, but yeah, it's not a good idea.