# Ncurses c/c++ - getstr() non declared char array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, ncurses

I'm writing little project in Ncurses. There is code where I have a problem.

```
 #include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    char *name;

    initscr();

    printw("Set your name: ");
    getstr(name = new char[sizeof name]);

    printw("Name: %s", name);

    getch();

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

I know that this code won't work. How do I do so this char array gets its size when user types in what he wants to type? Can program work not knowing size of this array untill someone type his name? I don't want user to type in length of his name. I don't want to declare size of this array by myself I want program to know what size of this array it needs to create. Is it possible? Can't think of anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ncurses/C/C++: Using getstr() and preventing overflow (There must be a better way to do this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735850/ncurses-c-c-using-getstr-and-preventing-overflow-there-must-be-a-better-wa)

Comment: There is no answer for me. I need to declare array when user types in his name. And in this post, size of array is declared.

Comment: I believe the only way to do this would be to read input one character at a time and resize the buffer as you go along...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I do so this char array gets its size when user types in what he wants to type?

You can't in *C*.

> Can program work not knowing size of this array untill someone type his name?

No. You have to make an assumption about how big a name could possibly be and provide a buffer to `getstr()` that is big enough.

> I don't want user to type in length of his name.

That is not necessary if the buffer is big enough for any name.

> I don't want to declare size of this array by myself I want program to know what size of this array it needs to create.

If you don't know the size of the array in advance, your program can't either.

> Is it possible?

No.

If you are programming in a higher level language that reads from the terminal and returns a string of the right length, what is happening "under the covers" is that the input is read into a large buffer, then copied to a dynamically allocated string of the right length that is returned to you. There only needs to be one "large buffer" than can be used by all of the input calls, and you never need to think about it.

However, in *C*, being a pretty low-level language, you basically have to do this yourself, so when you read input from the terminal, a pipe, or a socket, etc., you cannot often tell how big the input is going to be before you read it, so you have to read it into a buffer that you have "manually" pre-sized to be big enough.

Although not a perfect solution (there are subtle reasons not to do this), if you `#include <limits.h>` and then use `LINE_MAX` for the size of your input buffer, you are (almost) guaranteed that your input buffer cannot overflow.